# Mean of a time variable in Modelica

Tags: variables, average, mean, modelica

I have a simple model as follows and I intend to calculate the mean of x derivative wrt time(der(x)).

```
model Average
  Real x;
initial equation 
  x = 2.0;
equation 
  der(x) = x + 5;
  annotation (experiment(StopTime=10, __Dymola_Algorithm="Dassl"));
end Average;
```

The point is that it is a simplified code of an original one in which "x" is given by a CombiTimeTable. I need to perform several simulations (by several text files as inputs to the CombiTimeTable) that they do not have the same number of rows (different durations). In other words, StopTime is different from case to case e.g. here the StopTime is 10s for this specific case.
Is there any way to use a general equation to calculate the mean of der(x). I would appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer of [sjoelund.se](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68630336/8725275), I created a model which computes the mean value of `der(x)` via 2 methods:

- using the block `Modelica.Blocks.Math.ContinuousMean` from the MSL (instead of *Mean*, as it does not sample)
- computing the mean with `(x2-x1)/(time2-time1)` when the simulation terminates

```
model Average
  import Modelica.Constants.pi;
  import Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print;

  Real x;
  Real time1, time2, x1, x2;
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.ContinuousMean continuousMean;

equation 

  der(x) = sqrt(1+cos(2*pi*2*time))+sin(time)^2;

  // Method 1: Continuous mean from MSL
  continuousMean.u = der(x);

  when terminal() then
    print("Continuous mean: "+String( continuousMean.y));
  end when;

  // Method 2: Mean at end time
  when initial() then
    x1 = x;
    time1 = time;
  end when;

  when terminal() then
    x2 = x;
    time2 = time;
    print("Computed mean: "+String( (x2-x1)/(time2-time1)));
  end when;

  annotation (experiment(StopTime=1.0, __Dymola_Algorithm="Dassl"));
end Average;
```

Both values are printed at simulation end. They give a similar value as the mean post processing command which you can apply in Dymola on plotted signals:

[image: simulation output and plot of mean of der(x)]

Another possibility is to call the mean signal operator in Dymola after the simulation has ended (maybe in a script which runs your simulation):

```
DymolaCommands.Plot.signalOperatorValue("der(x)", SignalOperator.ArithmeticMean, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just calculate the mean as (x2-x1)/(time2-time1), given that you want the mean of der(X)?

Use Modelica.Blocks.Math.Mean if you want a numerical solution instead of an analytic. Note that it samples the signal so there will be some numerical errors due to that. In order to improve the accuracy, you need to reduce the period of sampling but doing so increases the time it takes to simulate the system.
If you do not need to use the mean during simulation it's also possible to use post-processing of the result-file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cannot calculate the mean of der(x) by (x2-x1)/(time2-time1) as other variables also involve in equation of der(x). I need the mean at the end of simulation and post-processing (exporting output into excel file and calculating the mean) is the thing that I am currently doing, but it is time-consuming. That is why I look for a better solution inside the Modelica environment.